# adjoint action of a Levi subalgebra

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras

We work over an algebraically closed field of characteristic 0.
Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a reductive Lie algebra and let $\mathfrak{p}\supset\mathfrak{m}$ be a parabolic subalgebra, respectively a Levi subalgebra.
There is the adjoint action of $\mathfrak{m}$ on $\mathfrak{g}$ and I would like to know how it decomposes into simples. More precisely, what are the highest weights appearing?
Does anyone know the answer or a reference? (Does it depend on the characteristic of the field?)

Comment: Concerning the parenthetic question as the end, there is of course some problem in prime characteristic because representations need not be completely reducible.   Anyway, the basic question here involves a very special case of the general branching problem (much studied in the literature, but not something I've actually done).   Usually there are no closed formulas, just a recursive process.   Basically you are restricting to a reductive subalgebra, or its semisimple derived algebra.  Think about type $E_8$, where the process isn't trivial to carry out.

Comment: P.S. Though it's wiser to stay away from prime characteristic at first, there is a characteristic-free aspect to your question: in terms of "Weyl modules" (obtained by reduction mod $p$), the Grothendieck group element you get by restriction in characteristic $p$ is the same as in characteristic 0.   But Weyl modules can have many composition factors, typically still unknown, depending on $p$.

Comment: Thank you James for the comment. Do you know some references where this branching for the adjoint rep is discussed? I'm interested only in the characteristic 0 case.

Comment: As you might expect, most of the explicit results are in math physics papers, mainly for exceptional Lie algebras and their maximal semisimple subalgebras.  See for instance *Octonions and subalgebras of the exceptional algebras* by
F. Buccella, A. Della Selva, and A. Sciarrino,
Journal of Mathematical Physics 30, 585 (1989).  But $E_8$ has $2^8$ Levi subalgebras, up to conjugacy.

Comment: P.S. It's useful to look at some special cases.   The advantage of the adjoint representation is that all weights equal to roots occur with multiplicity 1.   For example take type $A_2$, having simple roots $\alpha, \beta$, with a Levi subalgebra having derived algebra of rank 1 and simple root $\alpha$. The 8-dimensional Lie algebra splits into summands with highest weights $\alpha, \alpha + \beta, -\beta, 0$ (of dimensions $3, 2, 2, 1$).  The number of times the trivial module occurs (here 1) is found recursively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure that there would be a closed formula as Jim has pointed out. You can easily calculate it in examples because you can determine highest weight vectors in $g$ for $m$. Indeed, if $\alpha_1, \ldots \alpha_k$ are simple rooots for $m$, you just need to find those roots $\beta$ of $g$ such that no $\beta + \alpha_i$ is a root of $g$.

This will give you all non-trivial summands. The trivial summands sit in the Cartan and are easy to find as well.

And, if you are lazy or rich or both, just buy [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0840502281)

Comment: great, thanks a lot!
isn't it $\beta+\alpha_i$ not a root of $g$?

Comment: It could be a root of $g$, then $[e_\beta, e_{\alpha_i}]$ is a mutliple of $e_{\beta+{\alpha_i}}$. But if it is not, $[e_\beta, e_{\alpha_i}]=0$, and that os what determines the highest weight vector...

Comment: P.S. For some reason I once acquired a more elaborate book of tables by W.G. McKay and J. Patera:
*Tables of dimensions, indices, and branching rules for representations of simple Lie algebras.*
Lecture Notes in Pure and Applied Mathematics, 69.
Marcel Dekker, Inc., New York, 1981. v+317 pp.  (Any offers?)  Computers seem to have reolaced most tables.

Comment: @Bugs Bunny: I read again your answer and I must had missed the "no" in front of $\beta+\alpha_i$; that was what I wanted to say in my comment.

Comment: @BB: Why do you specify that $\beta$ should be a *positive* root?

Comment: huh? It must be a mistake...